# Second prepare statement doesn't work even sql is correct

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a problem with my search functionality.

When we hit search first we search by post title, post author and post tags in posts table. When we don't have any result then I want to search by category name in category table.

When there is no result in first search query then we get from category table category_id and try to find by this category_id posts from post table in 3rd query.

Unfortunately when it hit 2nd query I get back string: "No Result of Search. Try again later.".

Additionally I get this 2nd query string for debugging purposes and it is:

```
SELECT cat_id FROM categories WHERE cat_title LIKE '%HTML%'
```

When I run this query in phpmyadmin it return 1 row as it suposed to but in my php code it doesn't work. Don't know why. Maybe something is wrong with this prepare statements for example with close methods.

I am using in my code 3 stmt queries. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) {

        $search = escape($_POST['search']);
        $search = "%{$search}%";

   //FIRST WE ARE LOOKING BY TITLE, TAGS AND AUTHOR.

   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT post_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "posts WHERE post_tags LIKE ? OR post_title LIKE ? OR post_author LIKE ?");

   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $search, $search, $search);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   confirmQuery($stmt);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $post_id, $post_title, $post_author, $post_date, $post_image, $post_content, $post_tags);

   mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);  
   if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) === 0) {
           mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

           //NOW WE ARE LOOKING BY CATEGORY

           $search = escape($_POST['search']);
           $search = "'%{$search}%'";

           $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT cat_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE cat_title LIKE ?");
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $search);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
           confirmQuery($stmt1);
           mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $cat_id);
           mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1);
           mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);  
           if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt1) === 0) {

                //NO RESULT IN FIRST SEARCH AND SECOND SEARCH QUERY                

                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);

                echo "<h1 class='search-no-result'>No Result of Search. Try again later.</h1>";

                //DELETE THIS LATER.
                echo "<h1 class='search-no-result'>SELECT cat_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE cat_title LIKE {$search}</h1>";
                //--------------------
                $no_result = true;

           //IF THERE IS CATEGORY LIKE SEARCHED
           } else {

           //WE ARE LOOKING FOR POST FROM THIS CATEGORY

           $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT post_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "posts WHERE post_category_id = ?");

           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "i", $cat_id);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
           confirmQuery($stmt2);
           mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $post_id, $post_title, $post_author, $post_date, $post_image, $post_content, $post_tags);
        }
     } else {
           $no_result = false;
     }
   } else {
       redirect("/Udemy/cms/index");
 }
```

Additionally I can say that search works well with Title, Author, Tags search. Only with Category fails.

So what is the problem?

Something wrong with stmt queries or something else ?

//EDIT

I changed scond query to :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE cat_title LIKE ?";
```

The result is :

> No Result of Search. Try again later. SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM
>   categories WHERE cat_title LIKE '%html%' | cnt is 0

So apparently something is wrong with sql query but when I type this query in phpmyadmin I get this result:

> cnt 1

I think the error is because I make second prepare statement after first but I thought $stmt->close() would make it good. Maybe this is the case but I am not sure.

Do you have any ideas how to solve that ?

Comment: I wonder why you use `===` on mysqli_stmt_num_rows, since this function returns an integer...  Have you tried with just `==`?

Comment: @Nic3500 I tried your solution and still got the same result in meaning no result of search. It should return 1 row if it would be correct.

Comment: I have deeply inspected your code and I see nothing wrong. its weird. I  see something to improve perfs on first query

Comment: Do this test to eliminate some possibilities, change your query on categories to this `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE cat_title LIKE ?` It  SHOULD return ONE record. If it does not return a record, it's not the database and the issue is before the query.

Comment: @ThomasG I just edited post. I added query you provided and it doesn't return one record. It return 0 records. Maybe error is with store_result but I close first stmt so it should not be a problem. What do you think ?